# Adding page numbering, header and footer when Excel has been converted to pdf using C#

Tags: c#, excel, pdf

I have been working in a C# MVC Application (Visual Studio 2012). I need to create an Excel file and export it in pdf using c#. But, my future pdf document has to have a header, a footer and page numbering. How to implement them in c#? Thank you in advance for any help. The code that I have used for converting an Excel document with a chart to pdf is below:

```
        Excel.Application xlApp;
        Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
        Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
        object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

        xlApp = new Excel.Application();
        xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(misValue);
        xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);

        //add data 
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 1] = "";
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 2] = "Student1";
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 3] = "Student2";
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 4] = "Student3";

        xlWorkSheet.Cells[2, 1] = "Term1";
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[2, 2] = "80";
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[2, 3] = "65";
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[2, 4] = "45";

        xlWorkSheet.Cells[3, 1] = "Term2";
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[3, 2] = "78";
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[3, 3] = "72";
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[3, 4] = "60";

        xlWorkSheet.Cells[4, 1] = "Term3";
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[4, 2] = "82";
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[4, 3] = "80";
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[4, 4] = "65";

        xlWorkSheet.Cells[5, 1] = "Term4";
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[5, 2] = "75";
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[5, 3] = "82";
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[5, 4] = "68";

        xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 2].Font.Bold = true;
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 3].Font.Bold = true;
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 4].Font.Bold = true;

        Excel.Range chartRange;

        Excel.ChartObjects xlCharts = (Excel.ChartObjects)xlWorkSheet.ChartObjects(Type.Missing);
        Excel.ChartObject myChart = (Excel.ChartObject)xlCharts.Add(10, 80, 300, 250);
        Excel.Chart chartPage = myChart.Chart;

        chartRange = xlWorkSheet.get_Range("A1", "d5");
        chartPage.SetSourceData(chartRange, misValue);
        chartPage.ChartType = Excel.XlChartType.xlColumnClustered;


        xlWorkBook.ExportAsFixedFormat(Excel.XlFixedFormatType.xlTypePDF, "z:\\Brisi\\ExcelToPdf.pdf");
        xlWorkBook.Close(true, misValue, misValue);
        xlApp.Quit();
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2499448/display-page-numbers-in-a-excel-sheet-generated-using-c-net

Comment: Thank you very much @Yaman :)

Comment: Most welcome @alenan2016